# fail to install ui-bootstrap in angular-seed

Tags: angular-seed

I cloned the project and npm start successfully. However, when I want to npm install ui-bootstrap, it doesn't work.

> ➜ angular-seed git:(master) ✗ node -v
>   v10.15.3
>   ➜ angular-seed git:(master) ✗ npm -v
>   6.4.1

```
<div class="dropdown" uib-dropdown auto-close="outsideClick">
<input type="text" uib-dropdown-toggle placeholder="请选择"/>
<i class="fa fa-caret-down quickmodel_arrow"></i>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
    <li>
        语文
    </li>
    <li>
        数学
    </li>
    <li>
        英语
    </li>
</ul>
```